# I cannot replace characters using Regex and variable

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I've been trying to use Regex in my Javascript codes for to collapse indicated gaps like the below. But I couldn't manage that;

**this works;**
`outputFile = outputFile.replace(/\s*<div/g, '<div');`

**these don't work;**

```
htmlElements = [
  "div",
  "form",
  "label",
  "input"
];

var exp = new RegExp("\s*<"+htmlElements[0], 'g')
var str = "<"+htmlElements[0];
outputFile = outputFile.replace(exp, str);
```

Exactly the same expressions except using variable. Also I checked my expression on here https://regex101.com/r/eJ5kJ2/2 and here http://regexper.com/#%2F%5Cs*%3Cdiv%2F. And I tried both on Chrome and Firefox too.

Is there any chance to overcome this issue?

Comment: still not clear what do you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape all `\`s to `\\` because you define your regex as string, not as regex literal

```
new RegExp("\\s*<"+htmlElements[0], 'g')
```

Beside that: you may want to use a html parser instead of regex to accomplish your task